# Cannot read certificate in Azure App Service linux container

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate

I'm deploying a .net core 8.0 web app in linux container in Azure App Service. I need to use a certificate to register the app to Sharepoint. Everything works correctly from my machine but I get the following error in Azure container:

> An error occurred: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password, the password may be incorrect. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password, the password may be incorrect. at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.UnixPkcs12Reader.VerifyAndDecrypt(ReadOnlySpan1 password, ReadOnlyMemory1 authSafeContents) at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.UnixPkcs12Reader.Decrypt(SafePasswordHandle password, Boolean ephemeralSpecified)

The password is correctly saved in Azure Web App Configuration and it can be read correctly from the code. Also the file path for the certificate is correct. This is the line of code where I get the exception:

```
 try {
      var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certFilePath);
      certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(bytes, certPassword, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);
```

I've tried with different KeyStorageFlags. I've tried with different certificates, both self-signed and from CA. All works locally (even in container) and it doesn't work when deployed to Azure. Any idea on where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I needed and should written clearly in the documentation is that the certificated uploaded into the container by Azure Web Service does not need a password. The password protected .pfx certificate uploaded to the web service is converted by Azure in a .p12 file that does not need a password to be read.

I just needed to read the certificate with:

```
 certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(bytes);
```